# Trouble with Silverlight opening Browser on click

Tags: silverlight, browser, popupwindow

I have the following code in a click handler of a Silverlight application (4). I have two problems getting this to work.

1) While the browser doesn't have pop-ups disable IsPopupWindowAllowed is returning false. Why?
2) If I ignore the if test, the window doesn't show. :(

```
if ( HtmlPage.IsPopupWindowAllowed )
{
        var options = new HtmlPopupWindowOptions
                    {
                        Left = 0,
                        Top = 0,
                        Width = 500,
                        Height = 400,
                Scrollbars = false,
                Status = false
                    };
    HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri("http://www.monster.com"), "_blank", options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all the following is done correctly, as mentioned on this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage.popupwindow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

> The AllowHtmlPopupWindow property must be set to true on the Silverlight plug-in.
>
> The call to PopupWindow must be triggered by a user-initiated click on a visible area of the hosting Silverlight plug-in. PopupWindow can be called only once per interactive user event.
>
> This prevents the display of multiple pop-ups during the course of a single click on the Silverlight plug-in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I 'The AllowHtmlPopupWindow property must be set to true on the Silverlight plug-in.' in FF or another browser?

Comment: In siverlight's object tag, you have to set it as one of the param tags.